# AWS: Lighsail Resource query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Is it possible to get a custom resource on lightsail?

1. 32 GB RAM,16 core CPU, 1 TB disk, 5 TB bandwidth.
2. The plan includes 5 IP addresses. What will be the additional cost per IP address?

Comment: For now, no, you can't connect more than 1 IP to 1 instance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! actually, I could find the option named as “Service Limit Increase” where they allow it increase limit.